# Get JSON data form a requested API Python Odoo

Tags: python, api, odoo, odoo-13

I am trying to integrate Odoo with a hardware machine. I have developed an API, this API will be called by the machine. The machine in each request sends data in JSON format the format of the data is fixed and can't be changed, I don't have any control over how the machine should send the data. I have to receive the data and make some operations on it. the problem is when I try to receive it in my code, it gives me an empty array I don't know why any ideas. here is my API code:

```
from odoo import HTTP
from odoo.http import request, Response
import json,requests

@http.route('/getData', type='json', auth='public', methods=['POST'], cors='*')
def getData(self, **obj):
    text = json.dumps(obj)
    print(text)
    if request.jsonrequest:
        # here I am trying to print it first
        print("obj...", obj)
        return obj
    print("Has been called")
```

this is the format of the data:

```
{
"Protocol":"json",
"Id":"hghhg76533426",
"Packets":[{
"Id":1,
"Type":"Transaction",
"Data":[{
"DateTimeStart":"2019-05-19T12:44:01",
"DateTime":"2019-05-19T12:45:14",
"machine":1,
"Transaction":15,
"Volume":1.15,
"TCVolume":1.07,
"Price":10.00,
"Amount":11.50,
"TotalVolume":1231.15,
"TotalAmount":45611.50,
"UserId":1,
"ConfigurationId":"1234ABCD"
}]
}]
}
```

Comment: What's the result of the first print and the second print? is it the second print that gives empty array?

Comment: all of them, give the same result an empty array

Comment: Try printing `self` instead. It might come as the first parameter.

Comment: it's not working in the first print throwing an error (it's not JSON serializable), in the second print the path of the class